# How do I remove the tooltip in Grails 2.0.4?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

Does anybody know how to remove the tooltip in Grails 2.0.4? Currently all my mandatory fields shows a tooltip. I am trying to create a UI without the tooltip. I am using jQuery and jQueryUI.

Is there anyway that I could remove the tooltip? I think the tooltip is set by default in Grails 2.0.4.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by tooltip? Are you saying Firefox shows a tooltip when you hover over the field, or that it shows a "tooltip" when a field is invalid?

Answer (score 0):

you could use jQuery to remove the title attribute like so...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[title]').removeAttr('title');
});
```

Comment: Hi Micheal, Thanks for the quick reply. I checked the generated code from grails as such:<div class="fieldcontain required">
<label for="unitCode">
Unit Code:
</label>
<input type="text" name="unitCode" maxlength="5" required="" value="" size="10" id="unitCode" />
<span class="required-indicator">*</span>
</div> and I don't see any 'title' attribute. The tooltip only shows up if I use Firefox and Chrome. Not for Safari. Is this a browser issue? or is it because of HTML 5?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is html 5 related.  Do the fields have "required" in the tags (which I know grails puts in by default when performing scaffolding)?  If so, the browser will check that those fields are filled in and prompt the user if they are not before submission.  This was driving me bonkers trying to figure out what was going on.